# How to plus month in Golang with expected result

Tags: go

This is my code in Golang

```
dateTime := "2023-01-31T15:51:00Z"
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:00Z"

time, _ := time.Parse(layout, dateTime)

next1Month := time.AddDate(0, 1, 0) // result is 2023-03-03 15:51:00 +0000 UTC
next2Month := time.AddDate(0, 2, 0) // result is 2023-03-31 15:51:00 +0000 UTC
next3Month := time.AddDate(0, 3, 0) // result is 2023-05-01 15:51:00 +0000 UTC
```

My expectations

```
next1Month is  2023-02-28 15:51:00 +0000 UTC
next2Month is 2023-03-31 15:51:00 +0000 UTC
next3Month is 2023-04-31 15:51:00 +0000 UTC
```

Please help me with any keyword or solution to resolve it.

Comment: Why do you expect a result that differs from the documented behavior?

Comment: April has 30 days. `next3Month is 2023-04-31 15:51:00 +0000 UTC` should be `next3Month is 2023-04-30 15:51:00 +0000 UTC`

Answer (score -1):

`AddDate` is just performing basic math, but you seem to be looking for "the last day of the month", which is *not* simple math, it requires logic. You'll have to implement that logic. For example, you could use the 1st of each month and subtract 1 day: https://go.dev/play/p/Prc7_5rY3K9

```
dateTime := "2023-02-01T15:51:00Z"
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:00Z"

time, _ := time.Parse(layout, dateTime)

next1Month := time.AddDate(0, 2, -1)
next2Month := time.AddDate(0, 3, -1)
next3Month := time.AddDate(0, 4, -1)
```

Output:

```
2023-03-31 15:51:00 +0000 UTC
2023-04-30 15:51:00 +0000 UTC
2023-05-31 15:51:00 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: My expectations is a function like CustomAddDate(startDate, numberOfMonthToAdd)

if startDate = 2023-01-31, numberOfMonthToAdd = 1, result is 2023-02-28

Comment: @anhduc.bkhn then write such a function, using the above logic.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it

```
func AddMonth(t time.Time, m int) time.Time {
    x := t.AddDate(0, m, 0)

    if d := x.Day(); d != t.Day() {
        return x.AddDate(0, 0, -d)
    }

    return x
}

dateTime := "2023-01-31T15:51:00Z"
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:00Z"

time, _ := time.Parse(layout, dateTime)

next1Month := AddMonth(time, 1) //  2023-02-28 15:51:00 +0000 UTC
next2Month := AddMonth(time, 2) // 2023-03-31 15:51:00 +0000 UTC
```